# Как запарсить json

Tags: json, xcode, swift

Как записать все cityTitle и longitude в массивы?

```
{
"cityTitle" : "София",
  "regionTitle" : "",
  "stations" : [
    {
      "countryTitle" : "Болгария",
      "point" : {
        "longitude" : 23.32434272766113,
        "latitude" : 42.69715881347656
      },
      "districtTitle" : "",
      "cityId" : 18032,
      "cityTitle" : "город София",
      "regionTitle" : "",
      "stationId" : 9860,
      "stationTitle" : "Central Bus Station, 100 Kn. Maria Luiza Blvd."
    },
    {
      "countryTitle" : "Болгария",
      "point" : {
        "longitude" : 23.32434272766113,
        "latitude" : 42.69715881347656
      },
      "districtTitle" : "",
      "cityId" : 18032,
      "cityTitle" : "город София",
      "regionTitle" : "",
      "stationId" : 10032,
      "stationTitle" : "Central Bus Station, 100 Kn. Maria Luiza Blvd. pl.43,44"
    },
    {
      "countryTitle" : "Болгария",
      "point" : {
        "longitude" : 23.32434272766113,
        "latitude" : 42.69715881347656
      },
      "districtTitle" : "",
      "cityId" : 18032,
      "cityTitle" : "город София",
      "regionTitle" : "",
      "stationId" : 9862,
      "stationTitle" : "Автовокзал \"Serdika\""
    },
    {
      "countryTitle" : "Болгария",
      "point" : {
        "longitude" : 23.32434272766113,
        "latitude" : 42.69715881347656
      },
      "districtTitle" : "",
      "cityId" : 18032,
      "cityTitle" : "город София",
      "regionTitle" : "",
      "stationId" : 9958,
      "stationTitle" : "Центр города"
    },
    {
      "countryTitle" : "Болгария",
      "point" : {
        "longitude" : 23.32434272766113,
        "latitude" : 42.69715881347656
      },
      "districtTitle" : "",
      "cityId" : 18032,
      "cityTitle" : "город София",
      "regionTitle" : "",
      "stationId" : 10368,
      "stationTitle" : "Центральный автовокзал, сектор ПАРКИНГ"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: домашнее задание?

Comment: Как будет правильно указать подобный запрос внутри clearJSON?

'temp.append(clearJSON["stations", "cityTitle"].string!)'

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko, нет

Comment: вы что то уже пробовали? что именно не получается?

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko я не пойму, как обратиться к элементам файла при наличии в нем квадратных скобок. Пробовал подобный запрос, где в файле были только фигурные скобки и тогда не составляло проблем.